# How can I save files downloaded from Download Manager in Android to app internal(filesDir) as now its not easy to access files in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview, android-download-manager

Here is the code i am tring to do the same when i am downloading anything from webView in android.

```
 webview.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, l ->
                val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype))
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...")
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                        var newuri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.shyptsolution.classproject"+ ".provider", File(context.filesDir,"fileName"))
//                request.setDestinationUri(newuri)
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                   context.filesDir.absolutePath,
                    URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)
                )
                val dm =context.applicationContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                dm!!.enqueue(request)
            }
```

But I am getting error in this that it is not a standard directory. How can I save the files in cache or filesdir??

I just want to see my files in the `files` folder shown in the pic below.

[image: Device File Explorer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DownloadManager` cannot download to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), as it has no access to that location.

`DownloadManager` is very limited in modern versions of Android, due to scoped storage restrictions. I recommend that you use something else, such as OkHttp, to download the content within your app to a file that you control, including onto internal storage.

Comment: I am trying to download google drive files with its link, I don't think using Okhttp I can download the Google drive files.

Comment: @RaunitVerma: "I don't think using Okhttp I can download the Google drive files" -- I believe that you are mistaken.

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                   context.filesDir.absolutePath,
                    URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)
                )` That is impossible code. You are specifying a complete path where you only have to specify a public directory name. A folder name. No path.

Answer (score 1):

> > request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(

Replace by:

```
 request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(
```

Comment: I tried it but I cannot see the files downloaded in the `filesDir` from Device File Explorer in Android Studio but I can see it in my phone. Also I cannot access the file using `var file=File(context.filesDir,fileName)`

Comment: Here is the code I added            `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,context.filesDir.absolutePath,fileName)` but I cannot see the file or access it except from the Download App in my Phone.

Comment: var file=File(context.externalFilesDir,fileName)

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,context.filesDir.absolutePath,fileName)` That is nonsense.  Better: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(subdir, ,fileName)`

Comment: `tried it but I cannot see the files downloaded in the filesDir from Device File Explorer ` Of course not. You would see it in externalFilesDir.

Comment: Can you please help me, I just want my downloaded files to be available in the `files` folder shown in the picture above?

Comment: CommonsWare told you that that does not go with DownloadManager. DIdnt you read that?